# Google Drive Api - Android 4.3

Tags: android, google-drive-api

Ok. Here's a question for Google.
I'm using GoogleApiClient to obtain an auth code which later I send to my backend server so it could exchange that code for a token and refresh token.
I use the exact flow that is described [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/offline-access?hl=de). This seems to work with one drawback. It does NOT work on Android versions 4.3 and 4.4.2. Obviously this is insane.
So I said ok. Let's try GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() to obtain that code. This is described [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth). This also exhibits the same behaviour. The flow works on all devices and android versions EXCEPT 4.3 and 4.4.2.
By not working I will elaborate and say that I do get the account picker, and I do get the consent page for offline access. But after I click OK in that form, the consent page keeps popping in over and over and over again until the app is closed or the user presses cancel.
So I said ok... let's try the [sample app](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-server-auth-android) Google provides. I can use my web client id, add a check to obtain an auth code. And... once again... the consent page pops in over and over and over. I never reach the onUploadServerAuthCode callback.
This is ridiculous. So Im asking here. What is going on?
I mean... the sample isn't working so it's not something in my code.

Or more accurately, how can I obtain an auth code on Android 4.3 using GoogleApiClient? Or can someone from Google answer this question? Is this a known issue? Is there a solution that I missed?

Thank you

Comment: You'll probably find that it is the version of Google Play Services, rather than the version of Android that is the problem, although the two are of course linked.

Comment: I thought about that as well... I tried different google play services versions. From the newest (7.5.0) and back until there were no callbacks available in the services. I got the same behavior each time.

Comment: Hi Alon, did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Hey @DanielB, unfortuantly no. I ended up using a WebView and call the REST APIs directly to get a login screen and then the consent form and from there I get the auth code back in the url. Split that and save the code.